# ArrayQueue is not applicable for the argument ArrayQueue

Tags: java, arrays, queue

I was having some problem when trying to perform a sort in Java. Here is the reference link that I found: [Sorting an array with Stacks and Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243095/sorting-an-array-with-stacks-and-queues). Basically I am in the same situation as him, just that his is an Integer Queue whereas mine is String ArrayQueue. Here is my sort():

```
private ArrayQueue<ArrayQueue<E>> Q;
private int n;
public void sort() {
    if (Q.size() <= 1) return;

   ArrayQueue<E> left  = new ArrayQueue<E>(), right = new ArrayQueue<E>();
    while (!Q.isEmpty()) {
        left.enqueue(Q.dequeue());
        if (!Q.isEmpty()) {
           right.enqueue(Q.dequeue());
        }
    }
    merge(left, right);
}
```

For my dequeue(), it is returning E:

```
 public E dequeue() throws ArrayQueueException {
         if(f == r){
          f = f -1;
          r = r -1;
         }else
          f = f +1;    
         size --;
         return Q[f];
}
```

As for the enqueue, it is taking E element as parameter:

```
 public void enqueue(E element) throws ArrayQueueException {
   //Code
}
```

The errors are at the left.enqueue and right.enqueue part inside the sort(). Error message as:

```
The method enqueue(E) in the type ArrayQueue<E> is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayQueue<E>)
```

I was following the reference link that I found. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't enqueue an `ArrayQueue` of `E`s into an an `ArrayQueue` that expects `E`s.

Comment: Check the return type of `Q.dequeue`. Provide the relevant code to replicate the issue.

Comment: I see but then the one in the reference link is Queue whereas mine was ArrayQueue. I do not think that .add works for ArrayQueue

Comment: The return type was E for dequeue. Let me update the question.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler error arises in this part of the code? It doesn't look like it should.

Comment: Provide this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have already updated the question. That's all the part which are related.

Comment: What is the type of `Q`?

Comment: Omg so sorry my bad. Let me update it again.

Comment: Ok, so, yeah, see my first comment.

Comment: Okay updated so what's wrong now? The dequeue returning E type and my enqueue is taking in E type as parameter. So why is the left.enqueue and right.enqueue is highlighted with error as the error message above?

Answer (score 1):

With

```
private ArrayQueue<ArrayQueue<E>> Q;
```

`Q.dequeue()` will return a `ArrayQueue<E>`.

With

```
ArrayQueue<E> left;
```

`left.enqueue(..)` expects an `E`.

An `ArrayQueue<E>` is not an `E`.

That's why you get the error

> The method `enqueue(E)` in the type `ArrayQueue<E>` **is not
>   applicable for the arguments** (`ArrayQueue<E>`)

Comment: I see but is there anyway to fix this so that my left and right remains as ArrayQueue<E> cause I need them for the merge(). I figured out a way to remove the error by replacing the type of left and right to  ArrayQueue<ArrayQueue<E>>. However, with these changes, it clash with my merge()

Comment: Any ideas? I am still stuck. Or any way so that my dequeue can return E instead of ArrayQueue<E>?

Comment: @Denise I don't know your merge algorithm, so I can't help with that. You asked about the compilation error, so I provided these details. If you have a question about merge sort with queues and that question you linked to doesn't answer it, ask a new question.

Comment: The merge() actually just taking in 2 ArrayQueue<E> parameters and the return type of this method is ArrayQueue<E>. I actually have not done the algorithm inside it and I just wanted to make the code with no error until the sort() part.